# Dropping artikel when converting Direkt Fragesatz to Indirekt Fragesatz

Tags: grammar-identification

> Direkt:"Sind die Kinder mit diesem Leben glücklich?" Nur wenige fragen sich das.
>
> Indirekt: Nur wenige fragen sich , ob die Kinder mit diesem Leben glücklich sind.

Why was the "das" dropped when we converted the sentence?

Comment: "It's Friday. I know this." becomes "I know it's Friday" without "this" in English too, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why was the "das" dropped when we converted the sentence?

This "das" is called a "Korrelat" (correlate). Basically it is a marker for some other sentence to signify where it would fit in. For example, your sentence could be phrased this way:

> Nur wenige fragen sich "sind die Kinder mit diesem Leben glücklich".

But "sind [...] glücklich" was already said in the sentence before and - to avoid the repetition, which would be correct but clumsy - a marker is put there meaning *put in here what was said before*.

Notice that not only previous parts can be marked this way. It is also possible to refer to something following. Like this:

> *Es* fragen sich nur wenige, *ob die Kinder mit diesem Leben glücklich sind*.

Here the "es" acts as the stand-in for the following relative sentence.

Comment: a) The word _das_ in the first sentence is not a “correlate”, but a back-referring pronoun as in _Ja, er wohnt in Köln, ich weiß **das**_. I only know correlates referring forward: _ Ich würde **es** begrüßen, wenn du dieses Mal pünktlich kommst._

Comment: b) In the second sentence _Es fragen sich nur wenige …_, **es** is not a forward-referring pronoun or correlate as in _Ich bin **es** gewohnt, früh aufzustehen_, but a so-called "Vorfeldplatzhalter" as in _**Es** sind viele Fragen offen geblieben._ The antecedent placeholder is omitted in the change: _Viele Fragen sind offen geblieben_, respectively _Nur wenige fragen sich, ob …_

Answer (score 2):

The 'das' refers to the direct speech, the first part of your sentence ("Sind die Kinder mit diesem Leben glücklich?").

As, in the second sentence, you do not have two sentences, where one has to refer to the other. Therefore you can drop the 'das', because it is more obvious, what the content is.
As @DonHolgo already mentioned.